# Prove the following (Generating function)$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\sum^{\ell}_{i=n}\binom{2i}{k}=\frac{2^{2\ell +2}-2^{2n}}3.$

Tags: combinatorics

Prove the following: (use generating functions)

n < L

$$\sum^{\displaystyle\infty}_{k=0}\sum^{\displaystyle\ell}_{i=n}\binom{2i}{k}=\dfrac{2^{\displaystyle2\ell +2}-2^{2n}}3.$$

Answer (score 2):

First note that since ${2i \choose k} = 0$ for $k > 2i$ and by the binomial theorem that we have the fact 
$$2^{2i} = (1+1)^{2i} = \sum_{k=0}^{2i} {2i \choose k} 1^{2i-k} 1^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {2i \choose k} $$

Now swap the order of integration and use the above to get

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}   \sum^{\ell}_{i=n} {2i \choose k} =  \sum^{\ell}_{i=n} \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}  {2i \choose k}  = \sum_{i=n}^\ell 2^{2i} = 2^{2n} \sum_{i=0}^{\ell-n} 2^{2i}.$$

Use the geometric series $1+x+\cdots + x^m = \frac{x^{m+1}-1}{x-1}$ to finish this off.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum^{\displaystyle\infty}_{k=0}\sum^{\displaystyle\ell}_{i=n}\binom{2i}{k}=\sum^{\displaystyle\ell}_{i=n}\sum^{\displaystyle\infty}_{k=0}\binom{2i}{k}(1)^k = \sum^{\displaystyle\ell}_{i=n}4^{i} =  \sum^{\displaystyle\ell}_{i=n}2^{2i} = $$
$$=  \sum^{\displaystyle\ell}_{i=0}4^i - \sum^{n-1}_{i=0}4^i= \frac{1 - 4^{\ell+1}}{1 - 4} - \frac{1 - 4^{n}}{1 - 4} = \frac{4^{\ell + 1} - 4^n}{3} = \frac{2^{2\ell + 2} - 2^{2n}}{3}$$